# Update a TextView on resuming main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, textview, android-activity, onresume

Friends in this code provided below, i want to refresh my text view upon resume from  play intent. But whenever i try to define my textview out of OnCreate but inside my main class (after static int score), my app crashes.

```
public class MainProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static int Score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Display Scores
        final TextView displayScores = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreDisplay);
        displayScores.setText("Your Score : "+ Score);

        //Play Game button activity
        Button gameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
        gameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent play = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.sample.game.PlayScreen.class);
                startActivity(play);
            }
        });
```

Comment: add the crash log and the onResume code for the refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class MainProjectActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView displayScores;
    static int Score = 0;
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // code to update the date here
    displayScores.setText("Your Score : "+ Score);

}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Display Scores
        displayScores = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreDisplay);
        displayScores.setText("Your Score : "+ Score);

        //Play Game button activity
        Button gameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.PlayButton);
        gameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent play = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.sample.game.PlayScreen.class);
                startActivity(play);
            }
        });
```

Comment: welcome friend!!!, if it is working then accept as answer for others help looking for same problem.thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with adding super.onResume();:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // The rest
}
```

I would also remove that:

```
final TextView displayScores = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreDisplay);
        displayScores.setText("Your Score : "+ Score);
```

from onCreate,and add it to onResume() since every time onCreate is called, onResume is called as well.

also change from public to protected onResume()

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        displayScores.setText("Your Score : "+ Score);

        super.onResume();
    }
```